# Android calendar layout and button

Tags: android, button, gridview, calendar, drawable

I am making a calendar inside a gridview and is inflating each "day" through the `R.layout.screen_gridcell`.

The calendar is inflating properly, but I would like to add a further function that when the user presses a day, the pressed cell will be highlighted using the `drawable` `calendar_tile_chosen`.

But nothing has happened when I press any cell.

### Question:

1. How could I get back the id of the selected gridcell button when `onClick` so that I can apply the `drawable` `calendar_tile_chosen` effect?
2. Since the user may click another day (day2) after day1, when pressing day2, how to set day1 back to normal layout? Need to remember day1 and refresh the whole calendar before applying the drawable calendar_tile_chosen to day2? This route seems so clumpsy..

### View getView:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
        }

        // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
        gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
        gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);
        gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
```

### OnClick:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
        gridcell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_tile_chosen);
```

### screen_gridcell.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_tile"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_events_per_day"
    style="@style/calendar_event_style"
    android:layout_width="10dip"
    android:layout_height="10dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
</TextView>
```

### calendar_tile.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >         
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@color/orange"/>
        <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" 
            android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /> 
    </shape>    
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" 
            android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Please share screen_gridcell.xml too

Comment: Sorry for late reply...I have updated the question with the screen_gridcell.xml and thereby the calendar_tile too~ =) thanks for your help!